# Bounds for analytic circles

Tags: cv.complex-variables, riemann-zeta-function, riemann-hypothesis

It is known that for certain particular entire functions $f(s)$ of first order, in the circle $|s| = p$, if $\epsilon$ is a positive number as small as desired, the following bound holds:

$$|f(s)| = O(e^{\epsilon p})$$

A classical entire function of first order is Riemann's xi function, written as:

$$\xi(s) = \frac{1}{2} s(s-1)\pi^{-\frac{s}{2}}\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)\zeta(s)$$

Is it easy to show that Riemann's hypothesis(RH), or Lindeloph's hypothesis(LH), imply this bound? If this bound is assumed, would both these hypothesis follow? It is known that RH implies LH, but whether LH implies RH is still a deep unknown.  Consider the function $f(\xi(s)) = f(\xi)$ defined by

$$f(\xi) - \xi\left(\frac{s-i}{2}\right) - \xi\left(\frac{i+s}{2}\right) = 0$$

An interesting question is whether, in the circle $|s| = p$, the mentioned bound $|f(\xi)| = O(e^{\epsilon p})$ holds. The function $f(\xi)$ is interesting in that it is easy to show that all its zeros are real.

@bojonnson thanks. You're right. My aim was to see if the bound held in the critical strip, and $\xi(s)$ was mixed with $\Xi(t)$. Since @GHfromMO makes key points, it's best not to amend my question, so other's can see the error and understand the thread. Strangely enough, the question arouse in my head from the following raw observation: It is a fascinating elementary fact, first seen by Jensen, that given a Bernoulli polynomial  $P_{2k}(s)$ and a Bernoulli number $B_k$, the map $\Xi(t)=\Xi(-t)$ shows that the critical strip is a cut of the complex plane $s$ where the difference $P_{2K}(s) - B_K(-1)^k$, divided symmetrically into $4k(-1)^k$ slices, creates $4k(-1)^k$ finite slices that can be mapped by a suitable infinite elliptic series running from zero to infinity on the real axis. Hence $f(\Xi)$ can be written for complex $z$ as:

$$f(\Xi(z))=\int_{0}^{\infty}g(t) \cos(zt) \ dt$$

Here $g(t)$ is defined by
$$g(t)= (h''(t) - h(t))(e^t -e^{-t})$$
and $h(t)$ is

$$4h(t) = e^t\theta(e^t)$$

$\theta(x)$ is the Jacobi elliptic theta function:

$$\theta(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\pi x^2 n^2}$$

Comment: Please use a high-level tag like "cv.complex-variables". I added this tag now. Regarding high-level tags, see https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1075/

Comment: Responses to questions should be made as comments or as edits to the question.  I added the text of the non-answer by the OP below to the question.

Comment: @BenWebster thank you. Yes this makes clear my mistake and might help others. I apreciate the edit. Best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like @boJonsson made a typo, mixing up $\xi(s)$ with $\Xi(t)$, defined, for $s=1/2+it$, as:

$$\Xi(t) = \frac{1}{2} s(s-1) \pi^{-\frac{s}{2}} \Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right) \zeta(s)$$

All the zeros in the following function $f(\Xi)$ are real:

$$f(\Xi(t)) -  \Xi\left(\frac{t+i}{2}\right) - \Xi\left(\frac{t-i}{2}\right) = 0$$

If you assume the bound $O(e^{\epsilon p})$ for the Riemann xi function $\xi(s)$, where $s$ is on the critical line and $|s| < p$, it seems highly likely that Lindelöf Hypothesis(LH) would follow. Both the specific bound for $\xi(s)$ and the Lindelöf Hypothesis are implied by the Riemann Hypothesis (RH). However, it seems subtle whether the bound directly implies RH, or LH.

That the bound and LH imply each other, might follow from the fact that the bound $S_1(t)=o(t)$ implies LH and vice versa. It is an interesting question whether $|f(\Xi)| = O(e^{\epsilon p})$ holds for $f(\Xi)$ in $0<Im(t)<1/2$, $|t| <p$.

Comment: It is known that $\xi(s)$ (hence also $f(s)$) decays exponentially in every vertical strip. This follows from the convexity bound for $\zeta(s)$ and Stirling's approximation for $\Gamma(s/2)$. In particular, for any $0\leq\sigma\leq1$, any $t\geq 1$, and any $\epsilon>0$ we have that $\xi(\sigma+it)\ll t^{2+\epsilon}e^{-\pi t/4}$. For example, $|\xi(1/2+1000i)|\approx 1.599\times 10^{-336}$, while $e^{-250\pi}\approx 8.052\times 10^{-342}$.

Answer (score 5):

The functions $\xi(s)$ and
$$f(s):=\xi\left(\frac{s-i}{2}\right) + \xi\left(\frac{i+s}{2}\right)$$
grow faster than exponentially on the positive axis, hence they do not satisfy the first bound. This follows from Stirling's approximation for $\Gamma(s)$ and the fact that $\zeta(s)$ tends to $1$ as $\Re s\to\infty$.

Comment: It is well known that there exist certain entire functions of order 1, that satisfy the bound mentioned. That all entire functions of order 0 satisfy the bound, is also well known, as you mentioned. Are you sure that the xi function does not satisfy this bound? is this not an open problem still?

Comment: It is not of order $0$, but of order $1$ and minimal type.

Comment: @Felixson My previous version was partly nonsense, sorry about that. I have updated my post.

Comment: @AlekseiKulikov Right. I fixed my post.

Comment: @GHfromMO Ok thank you. I see your point then. Still I'm not convinced that the bound is not satisfied, but I must be missing something...

Comment: @Felixson If $s=p$ is a large positive number, then $\xi(p)$ exceeds $e^p$. More precisely, $\log\xi(p)$ is asymptotically $p\log p$.

Comment: But it seems to me that the problem is still open for circles of sufficiently small radius, since the behaviors of $\xi(s)$ in short intervals is still a mystery. The question is trivial for large p, I agree...

Comment: @Felixson If $p$ is bounded, then the $O(e^{\epsilon p})$ bound is true for trivial reasons. Indeed, if $|s|<c$, then $\xi(s)/s=O_c(1)$, hence $|\xi(s)|=O_c(|s|)=O_{c,\epsilon}(e^{\epsilon|s|})$. I will finish this topic here.

Comment: Thank you @GHfromMO. Of course the bound is trivial for bounded p. But the differing speeds at which $\xi(s)$ and $f(s)$ grow to infinity faster than exponentially in the positive axis, is far from trivial...

Comment: @Felixson By Stirling's approximation, one can determine the size of $\xi(s)$ and $f(s)$ very precisely on the positive axis (as $s$ tends to infinity). There is no issue here, really. OK, I must stop now (this site is not designed and not meant for chatting).

Comment: Thank you. I will also stop here. Your point is cristal clear, but my impression is that @bojonsson might be assuming $s$ is on the critical line, or strip. I have posted an answer with some basic comments.